# How can I loop these MPI calls, or for cleanliness, turn them into functions and loop the functions?

Tags: c, loops, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm almost done with this program, I just need loop a certain section a bunch of times. The goal is to say if the "old energy" is within a certain range of the "new energy" (oldE versus E in the program), then the loop will terminate and print the new energy... that is to say, it's an energy optimization. For now I was just trying to loop it at all, so I made a y-loop that runs three times. However, when I run the program, it just stalls in terminal. I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. I think it has to do with memory allocation, so I tried freeing the memory and re-allocating it in the places that seemed the most sensible.

The area near the middle I labelled `// MAIN LOOP //` is the problem. If it seems unreasonable to try to throw that much into a loop, how could I revise it, such as by making chunks of it into functions? I tried making the MPI calls into functions, but that wasn't working for me.

Here is the program:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "mpi.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "assert.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  int N = 32;
  int dim = 3;
  float a = 10.0; // size of 3D box
  int size, rank, i, j, k, q;
  float **C, **Csend, **Crecv;
  float rijx, rijy, rijz, rij, Vij, E, oldE;
  float stepsize = 0.05;

  double Start_time, End_time, Elapse_time;
  MPI_Status status;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Request requests[2];


  float energies[size];

  float calc_energy(float **matrix) {
  E = 0;
  for(i = 1; i < N-1; i++) {
    for(j = i+1; j < N; j++) {
      rijx = pow((matrix[i][0] - matrix[j][0]),2);
      rijy = pow((matrix[i][1] - matrix[j][1]),2);
      rijz = pow((matrix[i][2] - matrix[j][2]),2);
      rij = pow((rijx + rijy + rijz),0.5);
      Vij = pow((1/rij),12) - pow((1/rij),6);
      E = E + Vij;
    }
  }
  return E;
  }

  float **alloc_2d_float(int N, int dim) {
    float *data = (float *)malloc(N*dim*sizeof(float));
    float **array= (float **)malloc(N*sizeof(float*));
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
      array[i] = &(data[dim*i]);
    }
    return array;
}

  Csend = alloc_2d_float(N,dim);
  Crecv = alloc_2d_float(N,dim);
  C = alloc_2d_float(N,dim);

if(rank==0){
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
        Csend[i][j] = (float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX/a);
    }
  }
}

// This function is to take a random number of matrix elements and change them slightly, but with a catch which is that it should be different for each processor.
float **randomsteps(float **matrix) {
  float **newmatrix;
  newmatrix = alloc_2d_float(N,dim);

  for(i = 0; i < N; i = i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
      newmatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
    }
  }

  int n = rand()%dim;
  for(i = 0; i < N; i = i+n) {
    for (j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
     int n = rand() % dim;
     if(i%2 == 0) {
       newmatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j]+((rank+1)*stepsize);
       if(newmatrix[i][j] > 10) {
         newmatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + (stepsize) - 10;
       }
     } else {
       newmatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j]-((rank+1)*stepsize);
       if(newmatrix[i][j] < 0) {
         newmatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] - (stepsize) + 10;
       }
     }
   }
 }
 return newmatrix;
}

// MAIN LOOP //
int y; // var for big loop
for(y=0;y<3;y++) {
  for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    if (rank == 0) {
      MPI_Send(&(Csend[0][0]), N*dim, MPI_FLOAT, i, 10+i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    if (rank == i) {
      MPI_Recv(&(Crecv[0][0]), N*dim, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 10+i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
     }
  }

if(rank==0){
  C = randomsteps(Csend);
  E = calc_energy(C);
  oldE = calc_energy(C);
  energies[0]=E;
} else {
  C = randomsteps(Crecv);
  E = calc_energy(C);
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
  if (rank == i) {
    MPI_Send(&E, 1, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 10+i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  if (rank == 0) {
    MPI_Recv(&energies[i], size-1, MPI_FLOAT, i, 10+i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
  }
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

int location;
int findmin(float *energies) {
  int location = 1;
  float minimum = energies[0];

  for (i = 1 ; i < size ; i++ ) {
    if ( energies[i] < minimum ) {
      minimum = energies[i];
      location = i;
    }
  } 
  return location;
}

if(rank==0){
  location = findmin(energies);
}

MPI_Bcast(&location, 1, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


if(rank==0){
  MPI_Recv(&(C[0][0]), N*dim, MPI_FLOAT, location, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}
if(rank == location){
  MPI_Send(&(C[0][0]), N*dim, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(rank==0){
  printf("%f\n",calc_energy(C));
  free(Csend);
  Csend = alloc_2d_float(N,dim);
  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<dim;j++){
      Csend[i][j] = C[i][j];
}}
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);


free(C);
free(Crecv);
C = alloc_2d_float(N,dim);
Crecv = alloc_2d_float(N,dim);

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

}
//END MAIN LOOP



free(C);
free(Csend);
free(Crecv);
MPI_Finalize();

return 0;
}
```

The code works, save for that big y-loop. If you just get rid of that, it prints a value.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Edit: I tried printing out a bunch of statements, and it seems to be stuck on this bit:

```
  if(rank==0){
    C = randomsteps(Csend);
    E = calc_energy(C);
    oldE = calc_energy(C);
    energies[0]=E;
if(y==1){
printf("yummy");
  }
  } else{
    C = randomsteps(Crecv);
    E = calc_energy(C);
if(y==1){
printf("yummy");
  }
}
```

It is stuck between the yummies

edit2: more specifically it seems to be     `C = randomsteps(Crecv);` that is the problem

edit3: and commenting this chunk of code in randomsteps gets rid of the problem, so this seems to be the cause. Still trying to figure out why

```
  int n = rand()%dim;
  for(i = 0; i < N; i = i+n) {
    for (j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
      int n = rand() % dim;
      if(i%2 == 0) {
        newmatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j]+((rank+1)*stepsize);
        if(newmatrix[i][j] > 10) {
          newmatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + (stepsize) - 10;
        }
      } else {
        newmatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j]-((rank+1)*stepsize);
        if(newmatrix[i][j] < 0) {
          newmatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] - (stepsize) + 10;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

That code was an attempt to take random elements in the matrix and modify their values slightly and uniquely per processor (by 0.05*rank, for example)

edit4: *aaaand* I figured it out. I just needed to switch `dim` in `int n = rand() % dim;` with `N`. A stupid typo caused me like three hours of panic. -_-

Perhaps I should delete this post now? Or would it be closed? I'm not sure what would be done in this situation

Comment: You have function definition inside the main, how can this work?

Comment: If I define functions like calc_energy, alloc_2d_float, etc. outside of main, it would work? Why is that?

Comment: No, but you should not use that it's a GCC extension that allow nested function to work, however my first comment was not clear.

Comment: You defined float **alloc_2d_float(int rows, int cols) with rows and cols but then the two parameters are not used inside the function. As I understand it, it should work because nested function can see variables from the upper function.

Comment: in findmin there is a for loop whiteout instructions and more {} than needed. It is difficult to follow the code. (i = i++) in the loop should be only i++

Comment: Thanks! I'll correct those in the post. 

Unfortunately the program still doesn't work...

Comment: I know, I clean it and now it compiles. From the for loops I understand that you must execute it with 4 processors but there is no check at all and the number is just put there. It is a good practice that an MPI program works also with only 1 processor. At least it's a lot easier to debug.

Comment: Just a last comment you freed the memory at each loop cycle, why? Maybe you wanted to 0 the arrays? Then use memset.

Comment: I did that thinking perhaps the issue was that when it went on to the next loop, data would be sent to an array that already has values. So it was a failed attempt at debugging..

Comment: @Chylomicron: If you solved this problem, please add your solution as an answer so that the question falls off the unanswered question queue.

Answer (score 0):

Your program hangs simply because you end up in a deadlock.

This is happening because your send/recv are not balanced, take your first loop:

```
  for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    if (rank == 0) {
      MPI_Send(&(Csend[0][0]), N*dim, MPI_FLOAT, i, 10+i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    if (rank == i) {
      MPI_Recv(&(Crecv[0][0]), N*dim, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 10+i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
     }
  }
```

**Rank #0** does `size` *MPI_Send* operations, one for every other process
**Ranks #1-N** do `size` *MPI_Recv* each (therefore (N-1)*size recvs are pending)! Only 1 of these `size` receives are going to be matched by Rank 0!

So, while Rank 0 can proceed executing the rest of the code, all other processes are stuck on a that receive. When **Rank #0** hits the barrier later you are stuck in a deadlock.

What you want to do is the following:

```
  if (rank == 0) {
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
      MPI_Send(&(Csend[0][0]), N*dim, MPI_FLOAT, i, 10+i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  if (rank == i) {
    MPI_Recv(&(Crecv[0][0]), N*dim, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 10+i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
  }
```

Also change accordingly the send/recv code at the end of the loop.